white on the left of the figure
I have drawn some lines but when compiling I have a large blank space on the side of the figure which is quite unsightly.

How can I remove it?
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}


\def\concentration{0.1}

\def\potZnIIZn{-0.76}
\def\pKe{14}
\def\logbeta{15.5}
\def\pKs{16}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\phPrecipitation}{\pKe-0.5*\pKs-0.5*log10(\concentration)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phRedissolution}{\pKe -0.5*(-log10(\concentration)+\logbeta-\pKs)}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\potstandZnOHZn}{\potZnIIZn +0.03*log10(\concentration)+0.06*\phPrecipitation}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\potPrecipitationBas}{\potZnIIZn +0.03*log10(\concentration)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\potRedissolutionBas}{\potstandZnOHZn-0.06*\phRedissolution}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\potZincateZn}{\potRedissolutionBas+0.12*\phRedissolution-0.03*log10(\concentration)}
\footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=14,
    ymin=-2,ymax=2,
    xlabel=pH,
    ylabel={$E (\unit{\V})$},
    ytick distance=0.5,
    minor y tick num=4,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid style={black!20},
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    axis line shift=1pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,% place de la légende,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    samples = 200,
    no markers,
    ]
    % courbe calculée :
    \addplot expression[domain=0:\phPrecipitation, red, solid, very thin]{\potZnIIZn +0.03*log10(\concentration)};
        \addplot expression[domain=\phPrecipitation:\phRedissolution, red, very thin]{\potstandZnOHZn-0.06*x};
    \addplot expression[domain=\phRedissolution:14, red, very thin]{\potZincateZn +0.03*log10(\concentration)-0.12*x};
        \addplot [red, very thin]coordinates{(\phPrecipitation,\potPrecipitationBas) (\phPrecipitation,2)};
        \addplot [red, very thin]coordinates{(\phRedissolution,\potRedissolutionBas) (\phRedissolution,2)};

        \node at (4,-1.6){\ch{Zn\sld}};
        \node at (4,0.5){\ch{Zn\pch[2]\aq}};
        \node at (8.5,0.5){\ch{Zn(OH)2\sld}};
        \node at (11,-0.25){\ch{Zn(OH)4\mch[2] \sld}};
        \draw[->] (11,0) -- (13.9,0.5);

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Unrelated: when using XeLaTeX you should not use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

The space at the left is caused by missing %. See What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?). If a % is placed at the end of lines 16 till 32 then the space at the left is gone.
